# Proper setup.py creation

Tags: python, python-3.x, setup.py

So I have a project which is structured as shown below:

```
project
├── src
│   ├── api
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── api.py
│   ├── instance
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── config.py
│   ├── packages
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── app.py
├── tests
│   └── __init__.py
├── requirements.txt
├── README.md
├── .gitignore
└── setup.py
```

I am trying to create the `setup.py` in order to call the `instance/config.py` from the `package/app.py`. So I created the following `setup.py`:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='project',
    version='0.1dev0',
    author='Author name', 
    author_email='my_email',
    packages=['api', 'instance', 'packages'],
    long_description=open('README.md').read()
)
```

But I get the following error:

```
...
      warnings.warn(tmpl.format(**locals()))
    package init file 'src\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
    error: package directory 'api' does not exist
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

So whenever I try to call the `instance/config.py` from the `packages/app.py` I get the following error:

```
    from instance import config
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'instance'
```

What do I need to do to the `setup.py` file to make it work? Should the structure of the project be altered somehow?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a nutshell, you have to create a root package `project` in project directory. See https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/ for more details. Then

```
from project.instance import config
```

Rename `src` to `project` and put there `__init__.py` with imports

```
from . import api, instance, packages
```

Comment: By "there" you mean inside the `src` folder? Because I did as you described but I still get the following error: `from . import instance ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

Comment: Convert your `src` directory to a python package. Rename `src` to `project` and create `__init__.py` along the path `project/project/__init__.py`